# Data from firebase database is not displayed properly

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am trying to retrieve data from firebase database, when i try to retrieve data for the very first time after installing the app nothing is displayed in recycler view but when i press back and once again try to retrieve data,its displayed properly, suggest me changed which i should do in my code so that data is properly displayed in first attempt

Method Used to return ArrayList

```
 public ArrayList<SaveAddInformation> retrieve(){

    AdvertisementRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot eventSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                SaveAddInformation mModel = eventSnapshot.getValue(SaveAddInformation.class);
                Log.d("DATA" ,""+ mModel);
                adinfolist.add(mModel);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    return adinfolist;

}
```

Adpater Class

```
 Context c;
ArrayList<SaveAddInformation> adinfolist;

public MyAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<SaveAddInformation> adinfolist) {
    this.c = c;
    this.adinfolist = adinfolist;
}

@Override
public MyViewholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.design_row,parent,false);
  MyViewholder myViewholder=new MyViewholder(v);

   return myViewholder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewholder holder, int position) {
    SaveAddInformation save=adinfolist.get(position);
    holder.titleTv.setText(save.getTitleS());
    holder.rentamt.setText(save.getRent_amount());
    holder.rentdays.setText(save.getRentDayS());
    holder.desc.setText(save.getDescriptionS());

    holder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), save.getImageuri());

  //  holder.titleTv.setText((CharSequence) adinfolist.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return adinfolist.size();
}
```

}

ViewHolder Class

```
 public MyViewholder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    titleTv=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Titletextv);

    rentamt=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.rent_amount);
    rentdays=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.days_rent);
    desc=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.descTV);




}

public void setImage(Context applicationContext, String imageuri) {

    adimg=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ad_image);

    // We Need TO pass Context

    Picasso.with(applicationContext).load(imageuri).into(adimg);



}
```

Comment: Firebase loads data asynchronously. By the time your return `adinfolist`, is hasn't been populated yet. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener

Comment: Actually i am new to the android development can you please elaborate what you mean to say with respect to my code.

Comment: @PriyankaKadam my answer didn't help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that the code has no errors, I would like to remind you that Firebase connections are async.
So the first time the function `retrieve()` returns the value of arrayList is actually empty.
What you can do is call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after the for loop in `onDataChange()` method.